# How to understand exact value ScopedProxyMode.Default for certain application?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, proxy, inversion-of-control

according `ScopedProxyMode` enum  documentation 
value

```
DEFAULT
Default typically equals NO, unless a different default has been configured at the component-scan instruction level.
```

I use spring boot and I have not ideas how can I understand which `ScopedProxyMode` uses

Is where way to know this information?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [@SpringBootApplication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) annotation, you will find that it is internally referencing a [@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#scopedProxy--) annotation.

Which in turn controls the `ScopedProxyMode` setting. If left unspecified (like in our case), it defers the decision to the [ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.html#setScopedProxyMode-org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode-) class.

Which `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` finally contains a real default: ScopedProxyMode=no. So to answer your question: if you have not explicitly change it, **the default Spring Boot setting for scopedProxyMode will be false**.